# Does MVC6 support Precompiled Views?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In < MVC6 I could have .cshtml files pre-compiled on publish, so that they didn't have to be compiled on first hit when requested.

Is it possible to precompile .cshtml files in MVC6?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer for Visual Studio 2017:

Edit your project .csproj from Visual Studio Solution Explorer and add `MvcRazorCompileOnPublish` and `PreserveCompilationContext` properties with value of true if it does not already exists

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
      ....
      <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
      <PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Add the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation` to your project via nuget or editing the .csproj

```
<ItemGroup>
     ...
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

---

**The following answer was only applicable to ASP.NET Core RC1. **

You can create a class that inherits from `RazorPreCompileModule` and override the `EnablePreCompilation` method to set razor precompilation as true.

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Razor.Precompilation;
using Microsoft.Dnx.Compilation.CSharp;

namespace PrecompilationWebSite
{
    public class RazorPreCompilation : RazorPreCompileModule
    {
        protected override bool EnablePreCompilation(BeforeCompileContext   context) => true;
    } 
}
```

In `Startup.cs` reference this method:

```
public class Startup
{
    // Set up application services
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add MVC services to the services container
        services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddPrecompiledRazorViews(GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCultureReplacer();

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

You can look at the precompilation example [project](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/dev/test/WebSites/PrecompilationWebSite) on the asp.net github page for the whole project.

You could also alternatively compile your whole app when you publish it.

[image]

which will publish the whole app compiled as a nuget package.

Comment: I tried this now with a new ASP.NET 5 MVC 6 application targeting DNX Core 5.0 and I get errors that `GetType().GetTypeInfo()` doesn't exist, but also `GetType().Assembly` also fails (but the editor works - apparently the `Assembly` property isn't in DNX Core).

Answer (score 21):

## csproj (VS 2017) Answer

Add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation`:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation" Version="1.1.0-msbuild3-update1" PrivateAssets="All" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Turn on razor view compilation upon publishing the project.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>true</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

See [this](https://github.com/aspnet/MvcPrecompilation/issues/71) GitHub issue for more details.

## xproj and project.json (VS 2015) Answer

Razor Pre-compilation was dropped in ASP.NET Core 1.0 MVC 6 RC2 but was [brought back](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1) in ASP.NET Core 1.1 using a tool which you can add like so:

1. Add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Design` under the `dependencies` section like so:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Design": {
    "type": "build",
    "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
}
```

2. Add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Tools` under the `tools` section like so:

```
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
```

3. Add a postpublish script to invoke view compiler:

```
"scripts": {
   "postpublish": "dotnet razor-precompile --configuration %publish:Configuration% --framework %publish:TargetFramework% --output-path %publish:OutputPath% %publish:ProjectPath%"
}
```

Comment: Just some links: [future work to add it back](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3917), and a comment explaining that [they couldn't get it to work with .NET core](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3993#issuecomment-175155831).

Answer (score 1):

Finally Razor view pre-compilation is supported as of ASP.NET Core 1.1.

Here is the announcement: [Announcing the Fastest ASP.NET Yet, ASP.NET Core 1.1 RTM](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/announcing-asp-net-core-1-1)

It said:

> The Razor syntax for views provides a flexible development experience
>   where compilation of the views happens automatically at runtime when
>   the view is executed. However, there are some scenarios where you do
>   not want the Razor syntax compiled at runtime. You can now compile the
>   Razor views that your application references and deploy them with your
>   application.  To enable view compilation as part of publishing your
>   application,
>
> 1. Add a reference to
>      “Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Design” under the
>      “dependencies” section.
> 2. Add a reference to
>      “Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.ViewCompilation.Tools” under the tools
>      section
> 3. Add a postpublish script to invoke view compiler:

```
"scripts": {
   "postpublish": "dotnet razor-precompile --configuration %publish:Configuration% --framework %publish:TargetFramework% --output-path %publish:OutputPath% %publish:ProjectPath%"
}
```