# Does Asp.net core 1.0 RC2 support compilation preprocess?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

As we know, Asp.net 5 RC1 supports meta programming. It means we can write some classes that implement ICompileModule under ./compiler/preprocess folder.The classes will be called in build time, runtime and design time.

In Asp.net core RC2, I don't see the counterpart. Does Asp.net core 1.0 RC2 support compilation preprocess? Or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor pre-compilation was dropped from ASP.NET Core 1.0 RC2 according to Muhammad Rehan Saeed in a followon answer to this question [Does MVC6 support Precompiled Views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33518206/does-mvc6-support-precompiled-views)