# Accessing pre-compiled views in asp.net core from another project/assembly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, .net-core

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41999045/share-views-cshtml-files-between-projects-in-asp-net-core-solution), I have now set up pre-compiled views in my asp.net core application which is compiling to a DLL from the command line using the

> dotnet razor-precompile

command. I have then packaged it as a nuget package using

> dotnet pack

and added the package as a reference to the project I’ve removed the views from.
I have then created a new class which implements `IViewLocationExpander` and set this up in the `setup.cs` method of my project and I can see it searching my new location for the views. However, I don’t know what to put as the search path for a pre-compiled view, as there are no .cshtml files in there. I simply get an `InvalidOperationException` with the view not found.

Has anyone done this before or able to suggest how I may add these precompiled views to the search path?

Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: **Bounty Info:** I am using net core 2.0.

Comment: **[This](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1169354/Pre-compiled-Razor-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC)** might help you. I did that back in 2011 or 2012, but dont have the answer handy.

Answer (score 2):

I was amazed, it directly worked this way:

I just registered into my main project a [custom ViewExpander](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt763233.aspx):

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorOptions(options =>
{
    options.ViewLocationExpanders.Clear();
    options.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new TestViewLocationExpander());
};
```

The expander itself:

```
public class TestViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
    {
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        if (context == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
        }
        if (viewLocations == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(viewLocations));
        }

        yield return "~/Test/Test.cshtml";
    }
}
```

Then I have referenced the *.PrecompiledViews.dll of my other project, which contains a Test/Test.cshtml.

And voila, every page in my main application was showing this one.

Comment: I need to use _Layout.cshtml from one project's *.PrecompiledViews.dll in another project. Is it doable?